# Filtering by nested RealmList item's attributes

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

I'm having issues writing a query to do what I want -- since I'm not sure it's possible from my knowledge base, I figured I'd ask a question here.  I know of other ways to do this, but I'm trying to write a query that would result in me being able to use the query as a managed object, other solutions I've come up won't provide that.  Here's the problem:

I have a SiteInfo and Level model, that holds the Site along with associated Levels:

```
open class SiteInfo(
    var orgId: Int = INVALID_ID,
    @PrimaryKey var id: Int = INVALID_ID,
    var site: Site = Site(),
    var levels: RealmList<Level> = RealmList()) : RealmObject()

open class Level(@PrimaryKey var id: Int = INVALID_ID,
                 var building: String = "",
                 var floor: String = "",
                 var site_id: Int = INVALID_ID,
                 var floorplan_url: String? = null) : RealmObject()
```

I'm trying to filter down sites, where list of levels isn't empty, and I've gotten that far:

```
realm.where(SiteInfo::class.java).not().isEmpty("levels").findAllAsync()
```

However, for a site to be valid, at least one of it's levels must have a non-null floorplan_url.  I'm not sure there is query syntax that could support this.  If anyone could let me know if this is possible, that'd be great -- otherwise to the workaround I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
realm.where(SiteInfo::class.java)
     .isNotEmpty("levels")
     .isNotNull("levels.floorplan_url")        
     .findAllAsync()
```

?

Comment: This worked.  Thanks.  I didn't know you could reference lists like that.

Comment: Luckily, link queries do exactly `if there is at least one of where ___ is true` :D

Comment: oh yeah, if you use Realm 4.3.1+ then you can do `import io.realm.kotlin.where` and you'll be able to say `realm.where<SiteInfo>().etc`